# inline C & vcl caching

Tags: c, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

I have the url

```
...../suggest?callback=jsonp9999999999999&term=something
```

I would like to strip out *callback=jsonp999999999999&* from the url, cache the rest *(...../suggest?term=something)* and pass the complete URL *(...../suggest?callback=jsonp9999999999998&term=something)* again to the backend.

When a second request comes of the format  *(...../suggest?callback=jsonp000000000000&term=something)* varnish must strip out *callback=jsonp000000000000&* check the cache for a hit and return the result from the cache.

Is this possible with inline C and VCL?

Comment: What is inline C? Are you talking about the C (e.g. ISO C99 standard) language??

Answer (score 1):

If the query string always starts with `"callback=jsonp"` then search for the beginning of that ([`strstr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) is good for that). Then just find the next `'&'` ([`strchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) is the function to use here). Then copy the first part to a new buffer, and concatenate the last part to that new buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, you can alter the req.url parameters just like you would manipulate cookies or other headers. [Here's an example](https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-3.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl#L59) of how to strip out the Google Analytics parametes before they are sent to your backend, the same logic applies here.